# Updating firebase in my gradle app module ruined my app. Going back to previous versions does not work

Tags: android, firebase

Before any changes my `gradle` looked like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and everything was working fine. Then I updated all of the `com/google...` dependencies to `10.2.0` version and `firebaseui` to `1.2.0` as the table here says https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries

Then I got some errors on `mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` line (sorry but can't remember what exactly) so I changed back all of the versions to `10.0.1` and `1.0.1` and I'm still getting error and my application crashes on start (this error is different than the previous one).

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.mnm135.emil.showsmanager, PID: 3837
                  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzdz(Ljava/lang/String;)Z in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzw; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzw' appears in /data/app/com.mnm135.emil.showsmanager-1/base.apk)
                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.<init>(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)
                      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)
                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5811)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5403)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5342)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

I tried Invalidate caches/restart, clean and rerun. Even rebooting my pc. Nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Edit:

I tried aaroncio's solution, removed `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` and I'm getting different error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.mnm135.emil.showsmanager, PID: 5157
                  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzzq()Ljava/lang/String; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzu; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzu' appears in /data/app/com.mnm135.emil.showsmanager-2/base.apk)
                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                      at com.mnm135.emil.showsmanager.base.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:34)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Line mentioned in comment is `mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();`

Comment: You screwed something with GooglePlayServices dependency, I saw undescriptive error like these and it was always Google Play Services, not Firebase for me.

Comment: Fortunately I sent to my friend old version of my gradle app module from last working commit and I went line by line right now. Both are the same. Current version and Last working version.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it removing the line about firebase-authentication in the build-gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
```

I removed the imports about authentication also, I was just making some experiments with firebase auth so its not important in this case, but to others may not be ideal solution.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like something changed with the last version of Google Services, I had a similar problem and solved it deleting the following line in gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately it doesn't help.You can look my edit.